# JXTreeTable drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jxtreetable

I implemented drag and drop in a JXTreeTable and it does not work good in the first column. I have to select the line first, move the mouse pointer else and then go back to be able to drag the row.

On the others columns it works fine.

I don't think there are plenty options, here is what I set :

```
    table.setDragEnabled(true);
    table.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
    table.setTransferHandler(new TreeTableTransferHandler());
```

Perhaps it's a bug.

Thank you for your help.